# Standards to be followed for implementing static util methods

Tags: java

My understanding of static methods are generally these are util methods and contain business logic. This business logic is applied on parameters passed to these methods and return some output, without maintaining state.

But can anyone please guide me, is there some logical capping/ best practice that how long should be static methods?

Is it like Static Util methods should not contain too much logic. They should be short and easily readable and doing small work units.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it like Static Util methods should not contain too much logic. They should be short and easily readable and doing small work units?

There are no specific rules that only apply to **static** methods. All your methods should be rather short, and easy to read. And of course, they should follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Meaning: any of the guidances that concepts like "clean code" provide work for static and non-static methods.

Having said that: you are actually extra careful about using static in the first place. It is an abnormality in OOP, as it leads to direct, hard coupling between classes, and it kills polymorphism. And when done badly, it can seriously impact your ability to do reasonable unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for reply @GhostCat. My understanding of Single Responsibility Principle is, it applies to Class. Logically it should apply to method as well but for Method specifically Open Closed Principle applies thats what I assume. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Also can I invoke other methods from my Static Util method to get formatted output and then apply business logic on it?

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal All the principles apply to everything, just in different ways. It simply takes a lot of experience to know how to do that. But yes, a method should have a nice telling name, saying what it does, and then that method does exactly that one thing. For your second question A) I don't understand what you mean and B) please dont start question ping-pong. Dont use comments to ask completely new questions. When some answer answered your request, consider accepting the answer. If you have another, really different question: ask a new question. Also note: you can't learn these skills ..

Comment: ... by just learning rules. You need to practice practice practice. And the only real way to do that: write code, and then find some more experienced person to review the code and give you feedback on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot and appology @GhostCat. I am very new to this stack overflow and your advice is really very valuable. Will remember it

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal You are very welcome. And drop me a comment in case you are going to ask more such questions ;-)